# Extract Datetime information from a string in a DataFrame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, feature-engineering

So I have the Edition Column which contains data in unevenly pattern, as some have ',' followed by the date and some have ',-' pattern.

```
df.head()

17                Paperback,– 1 Nov 2016
18    Mass Market Paperback,– 1 Jan 1991
19                      Paperback,– 2016
20               Hardcover,– 24 Nov 2018
21        Paperback,– Import, 4 Oct 2018
```

How can I extract the date to a separate column. I tried using str.split() but can't find specific pattern to extract.Is there any method I could do it?

Comment: `obj.str.extract('((?:\d+\s\w+\s+)?\d{4}$)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj = df['Edition']
obj.str.split('((?:\d+\s+\w+\s+)?\d{4}$)', expand=True)
```

or

```
obj.str.split('[,–]+').str[0]
obj.str.split('[,–]+').str[-1] # date
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `dateutil`

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
 
df['Dt']=[parse(i, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)[0] for i in df['column']]
```